# What does "Justicides" mean?

Tags: united-states

Context:   http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/

The contentment on that page is shocking but not unbelievable.   I've found credible (Washington Post) reporting of [similarly shocking judicial behavior](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1995/09/21/montgomery-judge-accused-of-sex-with-prostitute-in-his-chambers/c3ff25ff-a47c-43f9-967f-67aaee449f39/?utm_term=.088ba71768df) in the court system hearing my case.  Another more recent case is that of [Montgomery County Circuit Court Judge Audrey Creighton](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/crime/montgomery-judge-who-had-romantic-relationship-with-felon-to-retire/2015/06/15/39e63b9a-13a6-11e5-9ddc-e3353542100c_story.html?utm_term=.22c2639e9756) who had romantic relationship with felon and reportedly hid him from justice.

One opposing council I've faced was even Treasurer of the [Committee to Elect Sitting Judges](https://www.electsittingjudgesmcs.com/)... which supported Creighton with campaign contributions, and he did this with the full knowledge and even accolades of the bar association.   That attorney demonstrated what I thought was unprecedented ability to get rulings to his client's advantage.   The very concept that attorneys can contribute to the election of Judges who then hear their arguments leaves me with little hope of finding an attorney to represent me well in that system.

Comment: That word was coined by https://law.stackexchange.com/users/18505/iñaki-viggers , so you might be better off corresponding with him directly.

Comment: Yes, thanks Blue Dog Ranch.   I found the link on his profile page.   Is there a facility for direct communications on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Burt_Harris I believe there is none on SE. But feel free to post comments in that playform and/or reach me by email. My email address is displayed on the cover page of many of my briefs available there and also on the cover page of my [petitions](https://www.supremecourt.gov/search.aspx?filename=/docket/docketfiles/html/public/17-1576.html) in the SCOTUS.

Comment: @Burt_Harris I just [did](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/35952/what-does-justicides-mean/35953#35953). Thanks for your question, by the way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a question about the meaning of a non legal word. It might belong on English se.

Comment: Topics explicitly on-topic here include issue related to "Dealing with legal professionals."    It was helpful to me to know that it's a coined word not commonly encountered in the law so I don't use it in dealing with legal professionals, in particular in pro se legal papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does “Justicides” mean?

As @BlueDogRanch rightly [pointed out](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/35952/what-does-justicides-mean#comment64548_35952), I came up with that term. I am unaware of any prior use of that term, though.

Etymologically, it would mean *killers of justice* or *assassins of [the notion of] justice*, from the Latin [*iustitia*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/justice#Etymology) ("righteousness", "equity") and [*-cida*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-cide) ("killer", "slayer"). The term is in line with the denouncements of judicial misconduct and/or the judiciary's plain criminal conduct.

Comment: Equity is such an interesting word, and apparently so different from law.

Comment: I've actually become deeply familiar with equity concepts, studying for example Restatement of Trusts (2nd and 3rd editions) and the UTC and derived statutes.   I'm no lawyer, and it's been an expensive course of education.

Comment: The legal definition of *equitable* is *that which is right*. Ultimately, enacted laws, case law, and equity are aimed at procuring *fairness*.

Comment: I know the question is strictly about the term *Justicides*, but I should add that the website's full name *One Club Of Justicides* is a parody of the slogan *One Court Of Justice* that courts of Michigan and elsewhere like to display on their buildings and [websites](https://courts.michigan.gov/Pages/default.aspx).